# how to insert formula in word using vsto?

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto

I want to use formula  { = {PAGE} + 1 } in my word document, tried below sample but that didn't worked

```
document.Fields.Add(sel.Selection.Range, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldExpression, @"{PAGE}+1", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help

```
_wordApplication.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowFieldCodes = true;
try
{
    _wordApplication.Selection.InsertFormula("=1");                      
    _wordApplication.Selection.MoveLeft(WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1);
    _wordApplication.Selection.TypeText("+");
    var field =_wordApplication.ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(_wordApplication.Selection.Range,   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty, "PAGE", true);
    field.Update();

}           
finally
{
  _wordApplication.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowFieldCodes = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i created this :)

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application _wordApplication = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

_wordApplication.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowFieldCodes = true;
try
{
    _wordApplication.Selection.InsertFormula("");
    _wordApplication.Selection.MoveLeft(WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1);
    _wordApplication.Selection.TypeText("=");
    var field = _wordApplication.ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(_wordApplication.Selection.Range, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty, "PAGE", false);

    _wordApplication.Selection.MoveLeft(WdUnits.wdItem, 1);
    _wordApplication.Selection.TypeText("+1");
    field.Update();

}
finally
{
    _wordApplication.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowFieldCodes = false;
}
```